# get all sender's list from vmail directory

Tags: email, postfix, dovecot

I am trying to build an email list. I would like to get the email addresses from an email incoiming mails directory (vmail/..../cur).
I use dovecot, but I think it does not matter.
Is there a way to get all the sender's list from a /cur directory with ~30000 emails in it?

I have tried:

```
cat 1325153222.M840289P9721V0000000000000901I034001E2_2\,S\=2892\:2\, | grep 'From:' | awk '{ print $3 }'
```

Output: `<info@domain.eu>`

It would be good if it would run on a whole directory not only one file.

Answer (score 1):

Too long as a comment on [your answer](https://serverfault.com/a/949351/37681) but there are some assumptions that you make with your strategy of

```
find . -type f -exec cat {} + | grep 'From:' | awk '{ print $3 }'
```

that I would like to address.

---

The  `From:` header usually has the form of

```
From: Sender Name or Description <author@example.com>
```

where **last** (and not necessarily the **third**) field is an e-mail address  enclosed by `< >`. That means that `| awk '{ print $3 }'` may not always print the e-mail address.
 The NF parameter in awk contains the number of fields and by using  `| awk '{ print $NF }'` you will always get awk to print the last field/column on a line.

With regards to the subcommand `grep 'From:'` :

I would recommend matching only the first occurrence of a line that **starts** with `From:` with a regex as that will be the header line and any additional occurrences of the string "From:" might come from the message body. You can also stop after the first match with `-m`, which will be a bit quicker on large messages. So try `grep -m 1 -e "^From:\ "`

From a style point of view, you can always replace  `cat  FILENAME | grep STRING` with `grep STRING FILENAME` and simply use the `-r` switch in grep to recursively parse all files in your Maildir.

```
grep -r -e "^From:\ " -m 1 . |awk '{print $NF}'
```

Comment: Great answer, using -e "^..." and -m options significantly speeds up the search.  One comment: "\ " is not necessary at the end of the pattern, " " also works.

Answer (score 0):

```
find . -type f -exec cat {} + | grep 'From:' | awk '{ print $3 }'
```

This works well